# Selecting an element not next to an element being selected using pseudo code?

Tags: html, css, sass

Currently i am trying to animate a `div`. I want to try and start the div using the `:checked` pseudo. I don't want the div I am transforming to be right next to the checkbox(for aesthetic reasons). So I currently have two `div`'s that I am using. One for the checkbox and the other as a stage to play div's I want to animate/transform.

I know you can select elements that are below another element as long as they are the child of the same element using, `div + div{}`.

But I am wondering if there is another way to select any element after a pseudo element goes into affect on another element(that is not in the same parent)?

Pure CSS or SCSS if their is a way. I know with Jquery I can easily do what I want but I want to stay away from JS for now, if there is another way.

Well I guess I'll after wait for  the WD for `:has()` to come through.

Comment: no there is no way (duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/8620333)

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there any sort of proposal for this to happen? Because it seems like a thing that should be possible and not restricted to before and after elements.

Comment: we still need to wait, here is https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks. At least it's in the pipeline. I guess I'll just have to wait a couple years to do what I want without JS.

Comment: @JuanMendes similar but that post was about selecting the parent of the current element and I want to select an element with a completely different parent.

Comment: Same idea, you traverse down, not up. The performance implications of searching both ways could make this a crippling feature, that's one of the reasons it was never added.

Comment: @JuanMendes Not really. He has a link which is a child of the list element. He is trying to access the parent of the link. I have a title div, with a form and input field, and a stage div with a child box div. The input is a child of the title div and the box is a child of the stage div. Thus it's not really traversing down rather than up, but out and then down and then back in.

Comment: @JuanMendes I guess that is the case. Sad days. Oh well back to JS/JQuery.

Comment: @STOAM it's the same thing. the *parent selector* is the missing piece of puzzle here. Selecting the parent element of a particular child will make you go up in the dom to select another element down again

Comment: @STOAM  `it's not really traversing down rather than up, but out and then down and then back in`, are these alternative facts? :p you're just saying out instead of up. The DOM is not 3D

Comment: @JuanMendes I guess. I just think 3 dimensionaly. Technically it's up then down and then down again if you were going from element within a parent to an element in another parent. I just think of it kind of differently.